# PHP MKDIR inside server root but outside domain root folder?

Tags: php

I have a domain root which is a folder within the server root. How can I mkdir inside a different folder within the domain root?

```
ROOT > DOMAIN ROOT FOLDER > PHP MKDIR

ROOT > IMAGE FOLDER > MKDIR HERE
```

I need the php in the 'domain root folder' to create a directory within the 'image folder'. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can usually do something like this:

```
mkdir('../images/newfolder');
```

You may have to add more ../../ on to the front of this, depending on where you are running the script from exactly. Each ../ moves you up another level, so it seems like just one would work here given your example, but you have to be sure you are where you think you are.

Comment: I tried that but it came back with errors. I have echo'd $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and it gave me /home/companyname/public_html/mobi - basically I want to get to /home/companyname/public_html/images. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: What were the errors? From what you said that should work, unless you have permissions or other issues.

Comment: Lots of 'WARNING: mkdir()[function.mkdir]:No such file or directory in ... on line ...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use absolute path in your php-script.

```
mkdir('/root/images/new_folder');
```

Make sure that your web-server has permissions for writing to specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

I usally work from the directory my current script is located in and maneuver my way to the desired location from there. Works fine as long as you don't move you script. In addition, it will be easier to keep track of where everything is relative to the script.

You can get the current path with:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
```

Then appending `../` to go deeper etc.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work. Any suggestions? $path = dirname(__FILE__);
mkdir($path."../members_image/".$mid, 0777);

Comment: Yup. Doesn't seem to work :/ sorry, fairly new to all of this. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @EdzJohnson: Post your code in your question and the error-message you are getting.